# Scale ion-router-outlet to display width&height

Tags: android, html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I have some components, which are displayed via `<ion-router-outlet>` in my `app.component.html` file. The components resolution is 2160X3840, and I want to scale the viewed from `<ion-router-outlet>` to the actual display size, if it is 16:9.

I try to create a short game, and I need a system to support different mobile display resolutions, without looking weird. I think the easiest way is to set the components to the highest possible resolution and scale it down if the display isn't that big.

I tried this in the high res. components scss file:

```
:host {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

and then put the `<ion-router-outlet>` in a div tag:

```
<div [style.width]="displayWidth" [style.height]="displayHeight">
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</div>
```

`displayWidht` and `displayHeight` are declared in `app.component.ts` file.

The code above works with delight. I am able to resize the background Image perfectly, but tags that I use are displayed wrong. Something like a viewport or a module which allows me to scale the rendered view from the component would be great.

- cheers